# update sql table based on value in another table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

There are two tables:

```
       orders
____________________
order_id |   Stat
--------------------
   1     |  waiting
   2     |  waiting
   3     |  waiting
```

second table:

```
       product
____________________
order_id | product_id
---------------------
   1     |       53
   2     |       54
   3     |       54
```

order_id value is the same in both tables. I would like to update Stat from 'waiting' to 'done' in Orders table if product_id is '54' in Product table.

I tried this code but didn't work:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET stat='done' FROM product WHERE product_id='54'");
```

will appreciate your help :)

Comment: Please, please _please_ stop using the `mysql_*` extension. It's deprecated, issues notices, is unsafe, not maintained and will be removed some time in the future. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: Thanks for advising. Do you mean I should use it like this? mysqli_query

Comment: Yes, but you should _learn_ the alternative extensions because, even though at first glance `mysqli_*` looks a lot like `mysql_*`, they don't translate 1 on 1: the new extensions are a bit more complicated, and a lot more powerful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use JOIN something as

```
update orders
join product on product.order_id = orders.order_id
set 
orders.Stat='done'
where product.product_id = '54'
```

Comment: and also use order.Stat as it exists in the order table - so with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
do this it work for u

mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET stat='done' where product_id in (select product_id from  product WHERE product_id='54'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this logic to be embedded in the DB you could use an update trigger like the one beneath (pseudo code):

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.product_id = 54 THEN
        UPDATE orders SET Stat = 'done' WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id
    END IF;
END;
```